# problems Installing pyodbc in Mu editor

Tags: pyodbc, mu

I'm new to Python. I've been trying to install the package pyodbc but I am not having any luck. Using pip, I can install the package pyperclip. When I use "pip install pyodbc" I get a PYD and PYI file. I can "import pyperclip" into my application but when I "import pyodbc" I get a ModuleNotFoundError. I have the latest versions of Python 3 and pip.

In your response, please be as specific as possible and don't make any assumptions that I will know what you are talking about since I am new to Python.

Thank you for any help that you can give.

Tom

Comment: What OS are you running? Are you using an environment like Jupyter? What messages do you see when you `pip install pyodbc`?

Comment: It sounds like you are running `pip install pyodbc` from a normal Windows command prompt. From within Mu, try clicking the REPL button and then run `pip install pyodbc` from there. That will install pyodbc in the virtual environment (venv) that Mu is using.

Answer (score 0):

Gord,

I'm sorry but my information above was totally incorrect. I thought that the MU editor ran the "import" command, but I didn't execute it properly.

Below is what I have when I try to "pip install pyodbc" along with a list command:

---

C:\Users\Tom>pip install pyodbc
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pyodbc
Using cached pyodbc-4.0.32-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (72 kB)
Installing collected packages: pyodbc
Successfully installed pyodbc-4.0.32

I ran the "list" command.

C:\Users\Tom>pip list
Package    Version

---

pip        22.1
pyodbc     4.0.32
pyperclip  1.8.2
setuptools 58.1.0

C:\Users\Tom>

---

When I try to import the pyodbc package in the MU editor I still get the ModuleNotFounrError.

Sorry for the confusion.

Tom

Comment: You can edit your original post - This should not be an answer.